# How to allow copy and paste using virtualbox when host and guest are Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: virtualbox

I am simply looking for a method that makes copy and paste between ubuntus 22.04 (host and guest) work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On guest window: Devices -> insert Guest Addition CD image...
2. On guest window: Open the VBox_GAs_ CD on terminal
3. On guest window:`./autorun.sh`
4. On guest window: Devices->Shared Clipboard->Bidirectional
5. On guest window: Reboot the guest